# rmarkdown - format numbers for inline code

Tags: r-markdown

When I use inline code in rmarkdown the result comes out in exponential form. It seems to be random (though I'm sure it must not be) as to which ones work, and which ones don't.

Can anyone tell me how to get this number to display with 2 decimal points?

*Here is the data:*

```r
# AllStats

structure(list(Mean_CalcnetPd = 13919.45, Mean_CalcnetPd2 = 13911.91, 
    SD_CalcnetPd = 4458.63, SD_CalcnetPd2 = 4394.47, Outliers = 3L, 
    Outlier_Cutoff = 27295.34, n_Stats = 22675, n_Stats2 = 22672, 
    RegressionModel = "Predicted", 
    `as.numeric(n_Stats)` = 22675), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```

*And here is the text with inline code:*

The sample is further differentiated by including only contracted Alliance Providers. The sample size was `r AllStats$n_Stats`.

*Here is the resulting knitted html:*

The sample is further differentiated by including only contracted Alliance Providers. The sample size was 2.2675^{4}.

I have tried converting the n_Stats value to different types like integers, numbers, etc.
I have tried to find a way through dplyr or something to fix the number before it gets pulled into the inline.
I have checked the cheat sheet and this guide: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/

Comment: add `options(scipen=999)` and use the `?round` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was solved by adding `options(scipen=999)` and using the `?round` function as [Julian commented under the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/132681493).